# The Puzzle of Locating Points in a Quadrilaterally-Faced Hexahedral Creature

Tags: euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, interpolation

### The Disclaimer

This is ***NOT*** homework... I designed the story. I thought a name ***MIT*** would be funny, while something along the line of ***TULSA*** or ***SU*** will still be decent. I know the algorithm to ***Q3*** and [3D version of ***Q4***](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/winddocs/utilities/b4wind_guide/trilinear.html), and my major problem are the name of the local coordinate system, the terminology, the formulation of this mathematical question and possible generalization. Insights are welcome.

I'm with $10^3$ rep even though it's pretty weak, but at least I know when to tag homework questions and such. I'm not even immune to homework investigators?

### The Story

Long long ago, in the far, far away mystical wonderland of $3$ dimensional Cartesian coordinate system lived many geometric creatures. Nobody knew who first named the wonderland the *Mystical Itchy Territory*, but its geometric residents would from time to time complain the random itchiness concurring inside their body or on their surface.

The *MIT* creatures live under a strange rule: Every creature can see all geometric shapes and know the coordinates of any point, but when conveying information about a $n$-dimensional coordinate to others, *e.g.* $(3,4,5)$, it is only allowed to communicate with at most $n$ numbers in the interval $[-1,1]$.

**_Edit:** The creatures want a solution like depicted in the picture below and do not prefer ***bijections*** drastically different to what's depicted. A trivial answer like mapping every coordinate in $\mathbb R$ to $[-1,1]$ using $\frac2\pi\arctan(x)$ is not preferred by the creature, though it's appealing to me.

### The 1D Ritual

I just met this *quadrilaterally-faced hexahedral* creature, now my friend (photograph in picture (a)), who told me that his species have came up with a ritual to help locating the origin of itchiness **on the edges** so that others could scratch them.

The ritual is a simple convention plus an equation:

- The Convention: Tell others the itchy edge $AB$, let $-1$ represent a vertex $A$, let $1$ represent the other vertex $B$, any point $P(x,y,z)$ on that edge will be represented by a number in $[-1,1]$, by the following equation.
- The Equation: $\displaystyle a=\frac{x_A+x_B-2x}{x_A-x_B} \text{or} \frac{y_A+y_B-2y}{y_A-y_B} \text{or} \frac{z_A+z_B-2z}{z_A-z_B}$, whichever is defined.

To get the actual coordinates, they perform a simple linear operation (combination):

$$P = \frac{1-a}{2}A + \frac{1+a}{2}B$$

### The Questions

> ***Q1:*** What term describes this kind of mapping? What's the combination called?
>
> ***Q2:*** Relaxing $a$ to $\mathbb R$, what's this mapping called? What's the combination called?

Similarly, for itches on the surface, he suggests that he could tell others which surface to scratch. He wants to design another set of ritual similar to what's shown in Picture (c), however, he doesn't know how to represent points on his quadrilateral face in $[-1,1]^2$. Neither does he know how to represent any interior points in $[-1,1]^3$.

> ***Q3:*** Please help the creature-- given 4 vertices of a quadrilateral, map a point on the quadrilateral as the creature intended.
>
> ***Q4:*** Given all 8 vertices of this creature, upgrade the ritual. If possible, generalize the result to $n$ dimensions following similar conventions.
>
> ***Q5:*** What about other geometric shapes?

### Illustration of the Mystical Itchy Territory

[image: Behold the creature!]

Comment: Is this some MIT math homework/puzzle? The presentation is very odd and it's the kind of thing where a few key words+google gives the game away, but it would be very instructive to derive things yourself if you are not previously familiar with this. What have you tried for Q3-5? Or did you intend to post the solution yourself later on?

Comment: @MarkS. the fact it's the land of MIT also gave it away.

Comment: @MarkS. I coined the term MIT even though I'm not a student in MIT and in no way affiliated with MIT at all.

Comment: @user4140 It gave away our tendency of raising eyebrows whenever other people asked something that looked like a homework. Presumed guilty.

Comment: While I appreciate the idea, the flavorful language obscured the question and its source for me. If you had said "it was something my professor at MIT keeps in a drawer for some first year students to think about" I wouldn't have thought you "guilty" of anything.

Comment: @MarkS. Nonetheless, I would appreciate any mathematical insight you are available to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:** If you change $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$, you've basically invented 1D [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29).

**Q2:** Then you have [affine combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination).

**Q3:** If the quadrilateral is not a parallelogram then I'm not so sure there's a completely canonical answer, but several things may be satisfying. The algorithm you linked for **Q4** is just one possibility. Assuming the quadrilateral is convex, I might be inclined to say something like "convert the $(x,y)$ to four coordinates for a [convex combination of the vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) where basically we have a weighted version of something like $(2-y+x,x+y+2,2-x+y,2-x-y)$ (the x-forward vertices get the benefit of $x$: $x+1$ and the others get $1-x$, similarly for $y$).

**Q4:** In this case, I would similarly convert to a convex combination in a way like that if the hexahedron is convex.

**Q5:** Even [these generalized barycentric coordinates](http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/MHBD02.pdf) depend on convexity; If a shape is not convex, I'm really not certain what I'd want an answer to look like...

Comment: For parallelograms/parallelepipeds, you can just scale vectors in the directions of the edges and add them to a corner vertex.

Comment: Note that for Q3, only 2 numbers are needed to address the coordinate, much like the step in [Bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation). So These 2 numbers can give the 4 weights. It's possible to solve for the two numbers using the inverse algorithm suggested in Q4. Interesting reading material.